# Draw Sankey diagram with holoviews and Bokeh

Tags: python, bokeh, holoviews

How can I draw the following Sankey diagram with this data

| Source | Target | Value | Category_links |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 22 SPHYRNIDAE | CE | 3 | Critically Endangered |
| 27 TRIAKIDAE | CE | 5 | Critically Endangered |
| 67 DASYATIDAE | CE | 2 | Critically Endangered |
| 14 CARCHARHINIDAE | CE | 4 | Critically Endangered |
| 62 UROTRYGONIDAE | CE | 2 | Critically Endangered |

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to have a pandas DataFrame. Your table looks very close to the wanted from. Then call `hv.Sankey()` with this DataFrame.

```
import pandas as pd
import holoviews as hv
hv.extension('bokeh')

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Source':['SPHYRNIDAE', 'TRIAKIDAE', 'DASYATIDAE',' CARCHARHINIDAE', 'UROTRYGONIDAE'],
    'Target':['CE']*5,
    'Value': [3,5,2,4,2]
})
>>>         Source Target  Value
0       SPHYRNIDAE     CE      3
1        TRIAKIDAE     CE      5
2       DASYATIDAE     CE      2
3   CARCHARHINIDAE     CE      4
4    UROTRYGONIDAE     CE      2

sankey = hv.Sankey(df)
sankey.opts(width=600, height=400)
```

The Output of the code above is

[image: sanky]

To style the edges with a color add a column with color information (color string or hex string) to the DataFrame and pass the column name to the parameter `edge_color` in the `ops()` call.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Source':['SPHYRNIDAE', 'TRIAKIDAE', 'DASYATIDAE',' CARCHARHINIDAE', 'UROTRYGONIDAE'],
    'Target':['CE']*5,
    'Value': [3,5,2,4,2],
    'EdgeColor': ['blue', 'red', 'black', 'orange', 'magenta']
})
sankey = hv.Sankey(df)
sankey.opts(width=600, height=400, edge_color='EdgeColor')
```

[image: sanky with colored edges]

Or use the default colors from the nodes and pass them to the edges. To use the color from the left node, pass the column name of the source to `hv.dim().str()`. To use the color of the target node, pass the column name of the traget to `hv.dim().str()`.

```
sankey = hv.Sankey(df)
sankey.opts(width=600, height=400, edge_color=hv.dim('Source').str())
# sankey.opts(width=600, height=400, edge_color=hv.dim('Target').str())
```

[image: edges colored by node color]

### Comment

This code was run with bokeh 3.1.1, panel 1.0.2 and holoviews 1.16.0

### References

https://holoviews.org/reference/elements/matplotlib/Sankey.html#sankey

Comment: How can I get those different colours for each category as shown in the first image?